# Tangent Space View Direction based factor value remap

Tags: math, geometry, shader, trigonometry

I'm trying to setup a mask similar to what Fresnel produces. Unfortunately Fresnel gives pretty bad results at grazing angles so I ended up using this :

```
float mask = abs(-viewDirTangentSpace.x / viewDirTangentSpace.z)
```

[image]

This gives a nice results but I would like to have values that evolves linearly. Is there a way to remap the range so it behaves like this (Photoshop) ?

[image]

Comment: try `float mask = abs(atan(-viewDirTangentSpace.x / viewDirTangentSpace.z)/1.5707963267948966192313216916398)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Spektre it's indeed way better. Can you tell more about that ?

Comment: if you imagine  right angled triangle with minor sides `viewDirTangentSpace.x , viewDirTangentSpace.z` then their ratio will give you tangens of the angle you are looking at (camera  direciont vs. surface partial "normal" )... the tangens is non linear so applying `atan` on it will give you linear angle ... I just scaled the result to range `<0.0 , 1.0>` ... You can also apply pow on the result to change the behavior ... for example `mask = pow(mask,1.1)` or `mask = pow(mask,0.9)` ... which depends on that if you want to enlarge or shrink the black area ...